# SVN commits directories as if they were changed

Tags: svn, version-control

I am usually a Git guy, so SVN transition didn't cause much issues besides some things that baffle me to this very day.

I don't understand why sometimes SVN commits (I am committing from PHPStorm directly) contain directories?

For example:

If I have a script at `Project/Html/Bla.php` and I change the `Bla.php` script I will naturally commit that file as being changed and it will end up in the repository.

However sometimes when I change it, together with my commits I will see that both `Bla.php` changed, and that `Project` directory changed.

This would make sense for me if I renamed `Project` to `MyProject` or something, but without touching it, I don't get it why does this happen.

Is there some explanation to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All FS-objects (files+dir) have [properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html), which also can be changed and have to be stored as usual content-changes.

You can always inspect *all* changes in WC using standard `svn diff`